# Search query to find all tasks assigned to current user

Tags: 2010, search, keywordquery

I have a custom web part which runs a `KeywordQuery` to find all tasks across all site collections assigned to the current user.

The query itself looks like this:

> "ContentClass:'STS_ListItem_Tasks' AND AssignedTo:'" +
>   web.CurrentUser.Name + "' NOT Status:'Complete'"

The property `web.CurrentUser.Name` gives me the displayname, however some site collections uses Claims and the displayname contains something like `i:05.t|asdf saml v3|UserInitials@domain.com` which the search engine doesn't recognize and then it returns 0 results.

Is there some other keywords or unique properties I can use instead of AssignedTo which will guarantee that tasks for current user will always be found regardless of name - like Sid, or Email?

Comment: Have you tried if the `{User.Name}` token works in 2010. I have a feeling it was new in 2013, but it doesn't hurt to give it a try

Comment: As `|` is used as a separator in the claim `i:05.t|asdf saml v3|UserInitials@domain.com`, see if this question helps you http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121394/search-does-not-return-results

Comment: @RobertLindgren It doesnt seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: @NadeemYousuf Luckily that is not an issue that I have come across.